# MongoDB: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMore' of undefined after 101 documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a simple script that fetch from a mongodb collection. However, calling `cursor.hasNext()` or `cursor.next()` after exceeding the batch size always return an error:

```
(node:4681) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMore' of undefined
    at Cursor._getMore (/Users/engineer3/Vouch/mbs-data-extract/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:418:17)
    at nextFunction (/Users/engineer3/Vouch/mbs-data-extract/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:774:10)
    at Cursor._next (/Users/engineer3/Vouch/mbs-data-extract/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:202:5)
    at cb (/Users/engineer3/Vouch/mbs-data-extract/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:249:14)
    at maybePromise (/Users/engineer3/Vouch/mbs-data-extract/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:685:3)
    at Cursor.next (/Users/engineer3/Vouch/mbs-data-extract/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:234:12)
    at start (/Users/engineer3/Vouch/mbs-data-extract/fetch_data.js:63:34)
```

here is my code:

```
let conn = await mongodb.connect(process.env.mongo_url, {
    // readPreference: 'secondary'
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
let db = await conn.db(process.env.mongo_db)
let col = await db.collection(collection_name)

const query = { }
let _cursor = await col.find(query)
_cursor.addCursorFlag('noCursorTimeout', true)

let _has_next = await _cursor.hasNext()
let _length = await _cursor.count()

while (_has_next) {
    let _doc = await _cursor.next()
    _raw_data.push(_flatdoc)
    _has_next = await _cursor.hasNext() // crash after 101 documents
}
```

how do i prevent the error ? i know that the driver supposed to call `getMore`, but i'm not sure why it throws this error

Comment: I always thought `count` consumed the cursor.  Does it still crash if you remove the call to `count`?

Comment: omg, removing `count` fixed it! the doc doesn't say anything about it tho, how do you know ? please post an answer so i can close this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `count` to return a number, it iterates the cursor and counts the documents.

Since MongoDB cursors don't support rewinding, there is no way to go back and retrieve those documents from the same cursor.

You will need to either count or iterate the cursor, you can't do both to the same cursor.